# cómo filtrar búsqueda de tiempo real con rango de precios

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

La pregunta en si es fácil de responder, ya que solo pregunto cómo es la sintaxis de código que necesito.

Tengo un buscador en tiempo real que filtra datos usando `select`, o sea, desde una lista selecciono ya sea un país o marca, y se van filtrando los resultado.

El tema es que no sé cómo filtrar usando rango de precios (ej: de 500 a 1000 / de 1000 a 2000).

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya gracias.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

Filtrar por países (aquí me gustaría agregar otro `select` pero de rango de precios)

```
<div id="barra-de-busqueda">
  <h1>¿Qué deseas encontrar?</h1>
  <select name="busqueda" id="busqueda">
    <option value="">Filtrar</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
  </select>
</div>

<section id="tabla_resultado">

</section>
```

Les dejo el código que sirve de intermediario

```
$(obtener_registros());

function obtener_registros(alumnos)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'buscando.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data : { alumnos: alumnos },
        })

    .done(function(resultado){
        $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
    })
}

$(document).on('change', '#busqueda', function()
{
    var valorBusqueda=$(this).val();
    if (valorBusqueda!="")
    {
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }
    else
    {
        obtener_registros();
    }
});
```

Y el que se encarga de filtrar

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","minos");

$tabla="";
$query="SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id";

if(isset($_POST['alumnos']))
{
    $q=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['alumnos']);
    $query=" SELECT
            p.id,
            p.descri,
            p.precio,
            m.nombre_m,
            c.nombre_c,
            p.pais,
            p.imagen
        FROM productos p
        INNER JOIN marcas m     ON p.marca  = m.id
        INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.catego = c.id
        WHERE   m.nombre_m LIKE '%".$q."%'
                OR c.nombre_c LIKE '%".$q."%'
                OR p.pais LIKE '%".$q."%'
                                OR p.precio LIKE '%".$q."%'
        ";
}

if(!isset($_POST['alumnos']))
{
    $query=" SELECT
            p.id,
            p.descri,
            p.precio,
            m.nombre_m,
            c.nombre_c,
            p.pais,
            p.imagen
        FROM productos p
        INNER JOIN marcas m     ON p.marca  = m.id
        INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.catego = c.id
        ";
}



$buscarAlumnos=$conexion->query($query);
if ($buscarAlumnos->num_rows > 0)
{
    $tabla.=
    '<table class="table">
        <tr class="bg-primary">
                               <td>id</td>
                           <td>descri</td>
                           <td>precio</td>
                           <td>marca</td>
                           <td>catego</td>
                           <td>pais</td>
                           <td>imagen</td>
        </tr>';

    while($filaAlumnos= $buscarAlumnos->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $tabla.= '<tr>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['descri']).'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['precio'].'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['nombre_m']).'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['nombre_c']).'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['pais'].'</td>
            <td><img src='.$filaAlumnos['imagen'].' width="50" height="50"></td>
         </tr>
        ';

    }

    $tabla.='</table>';
} else
    {
        $tabla="No se encontraron coincidencias con sus criterios de búsqueda.";
    }

echo $tabla;
?>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está el rango de precios? No entiendo a qué te refieres con ese rango. ¿Podrías poner algún ejemplo en el que aparezca ese rango por algún lado en el formulario?

Comment: Es que ese es el punto, no tengo el rango de precios ya que no sé cómo hacerlo, solo tengo un filtro de países, y necesitaría uno de rangos de precios

Comment: Ahh, ¿quieres agregar un par de campos en el formulario para que el usuario pueda seleccionar el rango máximo y mínimo de precios al estilo del buscador de Amazon? ¿Eso es lo que deseas hacer?

Comment: Justo no uso amazon, así que no sabría decirte, pero creo que captaste mi idea. o sea, quiero que el usuario pueda buscar productos de a cuerdo a sus precios. Que pueda elegir productos por ejemplo: de 0$ a $500 / de $500 a $1000 y así. Es como que diga "quiero comprar estufas pero que su precio no sea menor de $1000 ni superior de $2000" y que al elegir "$1000-$2000" le salgan los productos con esa característica.

Comment: Lo que quiero preguntar es que si quieres que se texto ($1000-$2000) se introduzca dentro del mismo recuadro de búsqueda ¿o que sea otro recuadro adicional, aparte?

Comment: Comienza con `function obtener_registros(alumnos,precioMin,precioMax)` y agrega los nuevos parámetros a `data`. Y en la consulta agrega `and p.precio between` y el rango.

Comment: La idea que ese texto este en el mismo recuadro de búsqueda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que sabes cómo usar `ajax` entonces voy a enfocar mi respuesta al `query`.

Puedes usar dos `input` numéricos (***o dos `select`, como prefieras***) para recoger el rango de precios, envías esos datos por `ajax` y el `query` sería algo así:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE precio BETWEEN $precioMinimo AND $precioMaximo";
```

Con esto le estás diciendo que te muestre los productos que estén dentro del rango de precios enviado por el usuario.

**Edición:** para enviar el rango de precios usando solo un campo `input` o `select`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Elimina del signo **$** en el valor, tal que, al enviar el dato, sea enviado así: **500-1000**

Recibes el valor en una variable `php` y lo separas mediante la función `explode`. Con esto obtienes el valor mínimo y el máximo por separado:

```
$rangoPrecio = '500-1000'; //reemplaza este valor con lo que venga del formulario
$precioSeparado = explode("-", $rangoPrecio);
$precioMinimo = $precioSeparado[0];
$precioMaximo = $precioSeparado[1];
```

Finalmente, haces el `query` que te dejé arriba.

Comment: Hola, respondiste mi pregunta, pero....Cómo mando dos precios usando un solo select?? La idea es que pueda ver en el select una opción parecida a esta "$500-$1000"

Comment: @Andres90tl Edité mi respuesta para mostrarte una propuesta de cómo se puede manejar en el caso que planteas. Con la función `explode` podemos separar un string, en este caso el separador sería el guión - .

Comment: me vas a querer matar, pero ¿te podría pedir realizar cómo sería el select, el ajax y php? no te quiero molestar mucho, pero de verdad me cuesta entender la sintaxis :/

Comment: Si el filtro de países te funciona, no es muy diferente el de precios... Simplemente reemplaza los `option` del `select` así: `<option value="500-1000">500-1000</option>`. El `value` que escoja el usuario será el que se envíe por `ajax`. En `php`, antes de hacer el query, recibes el valor en una variable y haces el `explode` y finalmente haces el query. En [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3jyQxvmwY0) muestran un ejemplo sencillo del uso de `ajax`, es muy similar a lo que buscas. Haz pruebas y si tienes problemas, regresas a SO y haces tu pregunta.