# ¿Cómo logro que en mi buscador esté la opción de buscar por rango de precios?

Tags: php, html, jquery

tengo un buscador en tiempo real el cual busca lo que el usuario seleccione de los  `select` que se presentan, hasta el momento solo tengo la opción de filtrar por países, pero necesito agregar otro `select` de rango de precios (por ej: que en un mismo recuadro esté la opción de "500-1000") y no sé cómo mostrar eso en un mismo recuadro, me sugirieron hacer dos `select` pero necesito que aparezca el rango en un solo `select`. 
Les dejo mi query para que se hagan una idea de cómo quiero que se filtren los precios.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE precio BETWEEN $precioMinimo AND $precioMaximo";
```

desde ya, gracias.

Comment: De nuevo, te recomiendo que leas la [actualización a la respuesta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336801/c%c3%b3mo-filtrar-b%c3%basqueda-de-tiempo-real-con-rango-de-precios). Si no es claro, o no resuelve tu duda, deja un comentario en mi respuesta y tratamos de resolverlo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [cómo filtrar búsqueda de tiempo real con rango de precios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336801/c%c3%b3mo-filtrar-b%c3%basqueda-de-tiempo-real-con-rango-de-precios)